# Trigger to update fields upon updates to formula fields in Contacts and Accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field, account, contact

I am very new to Salesforce and I need to write a trigger which should fire on few formula field updates and should update the other fields in contacts and accounts. So something like this:

**Trigger should fire when updates are done to these fields:**

*From Contact object fields* - ED_180_Prior__c (formula date field), Prof_Status__c (text)

*From Account object fields* - M_Status__c (formula text field), Days_of_MT__c (formula number field).

**Trigger should update these fields:**

*From Contact object -* Pardot_ED_180_Prior__c (date field), Pardot_Prof_Status__c (text).

*From Accounts object* - Pardot_M_status__c (text field), Pardot_Days_of_MT__c (number field)

I have tried this so far:

```
trigger updatePardot on Contact (after insert){
    List<contact> conUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    set<Id> sAccId = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact con: trigger.new){
        sAccId.add(con.AccountId);
    }
    List<Account> lstAccount = [select id from account where id IN: sAccId];
    for(Account acc: lstAccount){
        for(Contact con: acc.contacts){
            //con.Address_1__c = acc.Address_1__c;
            con.Pardot_ED_180_Prior__c                = con.ED_180_Prior__c;
            con.Pardot_Prof_Status__c                 = con.Prof_Status__c;
            conUpdate.add(con);

            acc.Pardot_M_status__c                    = acc.M_status__c;
            acc.Pardot_Days_of_MT__c                  = acc.Days_of_MT__c;
            lstAccount.add(acc);
        }
    }
    if(conUpdate.size() > 0){
        update conUpdate;
    }
    if(lstAccount.size() > 0) {
        update lstAccount;
    } 
}
```

Can someone please help me if I am not doing it correct, or if I should change the approach as soon as possible? Also, should I setup workflow rules for every different field when this trigger should fire? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far

Comment: If you want to learn how to do this yourself, you should definitely complete the appropriate [Salesforce Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails).  If you want someone else to do this work for you "as soon as possible", then you should definitely hire a developer.  You can start on the [Appexchange directory](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/developers)

Comment: Updated my post above. Have posted the code which I have written so far - however not sure if this is even correct.

Comment: At a glance it looks fine, but we really won't know for sure- you need to run this yourself. If you encounter an error, add it to the post.